# Using AnyGenerator with Swift 2.2+ ("for in" loop support for custom classes)

Tags: ios, swift, iteration

Previously I was using the following function to make my custom class conform to the SequenceType protocol:

```
func generate() -> AnyGenerator<UInt32> {

    var nextIndex = 0

    return anyGenerator {
        if (nextIndex > self.scalarArray.count-1) {
            return nil
        }
        return self.scalarArray[nextIndex++]
    }
}
```

This is a similar implementation to the accepted answers to these two questions:

- [Add "for in" support to iterate over Swift custom classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099227/add-for-in-support-to-iterate-over-swift-custom-classes)
- [Add 'for...in' support to a class in Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730127/add-for-in-support-to-a-class-in-swift-2)

**But after a Swift 2.2 update...**

> '++' is deprecated: it will be removed in Swift 3

```
func generate() -> AnyGenerator<UInt32> {

    var nextIndex = 0

    return AnyGenerator {
        if (nextIndex > self.scalarArray.count-1) {
            return nil
        }
        nextIndex += 1
        return self.scalarArray[nextIndex]
    }
}
```

But this throws an Index out of range error because I actually need to use the pre-incremented index and then increment it after the return.

How does this work for AnyGenerator now in Swift? (Also, should I be decrementing rather than incrementing as the other two answers I linked to do?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I assume that your code refers to `struct ScalarString`
from [Working with Unicode code points in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272561/working-with-unicode-code-points-in-swift/31483262#31483262).)

You can do a Swift 2.2+ compatible "increment index after determining
the return value" with `defer`:

```
func generate() -> AnyGenerator<UInt32> {

    var nextIndex = 0

    return AnyGenerator {
        if nextIndex >= self.scalarArray.count {
            return nil
        }
        defer {
            nextIndex += 1
        }
        return self.scalarArray[nextIndex]
    }
}
```

In your special case however, it would be easier to just
forward the generator of the

```
private var scalarArray: [UInt32] = []
```

property, either directly:

```
func generate() -> IndexingGenerator<[UInt32]> {
    return scalarArray.generate()
}
```

or as a type-erased generator which forwards the `next()` method
to the array generator:

```
func generate() -> AnyGenerator<UInt32> {
    return AnyGenerator(scalarArray.generate())
}
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Good memory. So the reason I can forward the generator in my particular case is because `UInt32` already has it's own predefined generator. Is that correct?

Comment: @Suragch: No, the reason is that `Array` (or `CollectionType`) has a `generate()` method. And `AnyGenerator` has a `init<G : GeneratorType where G.Element == Element>(_ base: G)`.

Comment: The `carList` variables in the two answers I mentioned in my question ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26219833) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31730379/)) are also `Array`s (of the `Car` class). Could one also just forward the array generator there, too? And if so, when would you use the more general answer you gave here (the one using `defer`)? Only when creating a custom `CollectionType`?

Comment: @Suragch: Actually [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27636938/1187415) does it already (which I did not notice before), only without the type erasure. The `defer` example was primarily meant as a direct counterpart to the to-be-replaced `return self.scalarArray[nextIndex++]`, but it can be useful when implementing custom sequence types.

Comment: FYI, in Swift 3 `AnyGenerator` is renamed to [`AnyIterator`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/AnyIterator/).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just introduced a dummy variable?

```
func generate() -> AnyGenerator<UInt32> {

    var nextIndex = 0

    return AnyGenerator {
        if (nextIndex > self.scalarArray.count-1) {
            return nil
        }
        let next = self.scalarArray[nextIndex]
        nextIndex += 1
        return next
}
```

Comment: what if you dont want nil values?